# jQuery Selectors | Complex Selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a list like that:

```
<div class="cloned"><a rel="test" href="" title=""></a></div>
<div><a rel="test" href="" title=""></a></div>
<div><a rel="test" href="" title=""></a></div>
<div><a rel="test" href="" title=""></a></div>
<div class="cloned"><a rel="test" href="" title=""></a></div>
```

I would like to use jQuery to select all `<a>` with `rel=test` excluding all `<a>` that are inside div class cloned. Something like that

```
$("div:not(.cloned) a[rel=test]")
```

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exactly what you have will work:

```
$("div:not(.cloned) a[rel=test]")
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/y7xrZ/3/), make sure you're inside a `document.ready` handler if you're having issues, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("div:not(.cloned) a[rel=test]").css('color', 'red');​
});
```